# Pseudo pop-up textbox to update multiple form textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Form containing a checklist with several textboxes, txtObs1, txtObs2, txtObs3, etc. On click event on each textbox will pop-up (actually is a hidden textbox made visible) txtAddData. I can enter data in txtAddData and update the textbox with afterupdate event but I want to use the same txtAddData to update the rest of the textboxes on the form one by one.

```
Private Sub txtAddData_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtObs1 = Me.txtAddData
Me.txtObs1.SetFocus
Me.txtAddData = ""
Me.txtAddData.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub txtObs1_Click()
txtAddData.Visible = True
txtAddData.SetFocus
If Not IsNull(Me.txtObs1) Then
Me.txtAddData = Me.txtObs1
Else
Me.txtAddData = ""
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable to hold the name of the textbox:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private CurrentTextbox As String


Private Sub txtAddData_AfterUpdate()

    Me.Controls(CurrentTextbox).Value = Me.txtAddData
    Me.Controls(CurrentTextbox).SetFocus
    Me.txtAddData = Null
    Me.txtAddData.Visible = False

End Sub


Private Sub txtObs1_Click()

    CurrentTextbox = "txtObs1"
    SetData

End Sub


Private Sub txtObs2_Click()

    CurrentTextbox = "txtObs2"
    SetData

End Sub


Private Sub SetData

    txtAddData.Visible = True
    txtAddData.SetFocus
    If Not IsNull(Me.Controls(CurrentTextbox).Value) Then
        Me.txtAddData = Me.Controls(CurrentTextbox).Value
    Else
        Me.txtAddData = Null
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error 438 on line  If Not IsNull(Me.Controls(CurrentTextbox).Value) Then

Comment: Then your control referenced is not a textbox. A label?

Comment: It is an unbound textbox named txtObs1 placed on a subform together with all other. Also, I couldn't use Private CurrentTextbox As String, Private gives me error. Probably this is the cause of the error

Comment: `Private CurrentTextbox As String` goes into the Declarations' section. See edited answer, please.

Comment: That was the problem, everything is very well now. Thank you